# rsyslog 8.34.0: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/omuxsock.so'

Tags: rsyslog

My project requires forwarding log using rsyslog to a socket. rsyslog provides `omuxsock` output module for the same. When I try to use it using [standard](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omuxsock.html) example, I see below error.

```
rsyslogd: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/omuxsock.so', dlopen: Error loading shared library /usr/lib/rsyslog/omuxsock.so: No such file or directory  [v8.34.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
```

Could someone please help me in solving this issue?

System Info

1. Alpine container = v3.8
2. rsyslog = 8.34.0-r0

Full log :-

```
/ # rsyslogd -N6 | head -10
rsyslogd: version 8.34.0, config validation run (level 6), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/omuxsock.so', dlopen: Error loading shared library /usr/lib/rsyslog/omuxsock.so: No such file or directory  [v8.34.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
rsyslogd: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'OMUxSockSocket' - have you forgotten to load a module? [v8.34.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3003 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 30: errors occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.conf' around line 30 [v8.34.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/rsyslog_stats.conf, on or before line 15: invalid character '\' in expression - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.34.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
```

Comment: Are you looking library file `omuxsock.so` in `/usr/lib/rsyslog/` ? Which permissions does it have?
And please note: `Note that most packages only distribute a very limited set of plugins via the core rsyslog package. To use enhanced functionality (like the file input, database or mail outputs and many more), you need to install additional packages (there names are distro-specific, so they can not be given here).` (from `http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066`). Possible, you must install additional packages for Alpine Linux.

Comment: @Alexey - Thanks for your response. Yes, I think I had to install additional package to get this functionality, which was somehow not allowed at that time. I ended up writing my own python code to push info and solved the business use case.